# Unbold piped text in Bash

Tags: bash

The command `mvn -version` [outputs the first line in bold](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/ce35eff448f9fdf5f4e3e17ac0b16761f4e2a747/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/CLIReportingUtils.java#L61).

```sh
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.0  # Bold text
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_242, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-1058-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

How can I unbold this line and write only that line to output?  E.g.:

```sh
$ mvn -version | head -n1 | xargs echo -E
Apache Maven 3.6.0  # Still bold
```

A simpler example:

```
echo -e "Normal \e[1mBold \e[0mand Normal" | xargs echo -E
```

outputs "Normal **Bold** and Normal"

How can the resulting text be "unbolded"?

Bash version: 4.4.20

Comment: Why use `xargs` at all? And note that `echo -E` is nonstandard functionality -- in some modes, bash won't honor it at all except as instruction to print `-E`. (Same is true of `echo -e`, for that matter).

Comment: My interpretation of the `-E` flag was wrong, so yeah, it doesn't make sense here

Comment: *nod* -- all it does is prevent further backslash-escape sequences from being honored, but by the time they're already converted to terminal control sequences, there aren't any backslash-escape sequences left.

Comment: ...so, this smells to me like a duplicate of [How to script ANSI escape sequences from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416278/how-to-strip-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-variable), or -- more loosely -- [How to remove `^[`, and all of the escape sequences in a file using linux shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-to-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell-sc).

Comment: Probably also dup of https://superuser.com/a/380778/992125, e.g. `mvn -version | head -n1 | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924697/how-does-one-output-bold-text-in-bash Something like this ?

Comment: @abhishekphukan, opposite of that, the OP wants to *not* output bold text but convert it to be plain even though what they read as input has control sequences telling the terminal to make it bold.

Comment: A better duplicate is the following, which says to use `mvn -B` to suppress highlighting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638595/how-do-i-remove-colors-from-maven-output

Comment: `mvn -B -version` still outputs bold @Jon